# Unable to delete table using EPPlus

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I'm having an issue with a very basic thing. Deleting a table using EPPlus.
The problem that I'm facing is that from the code point of view (I've debugged the code, and in the `Worksheet.Tables` collection, the tabled that I called Delete on is gone. I proceed to save the excel and when I try to open it, Excel tells me that "they" found a problem with it, and if I want them to recover as much as possible. If I select Yes (because No closes the file) the table that I just delete through code is back again.

If I set the `ClearRange` property in the `Delete()` method to `true`, the table is still in the spreadsheet, but this time the header columns are gone, and instead Excel recreates my table with some default names (Column1, Column2, etc, depending on the number of columns the original table had).

I've tried to manipulate the `TableXml` property of the table, and it's still not working. Other than that, I've just read the Internet for about 3 hours with no apparent solution to my problem.

So, if anyone is wondering, the code for this is:

```
using (var package = new ExcelPackage(fileToWriteTo, templateToStartWith))
    {
            var workbook = package.Workbook;
            var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[WORKSHEET_NAME];
            worksheet.Tables.Delete("dynamicTable", true);
            //worksheet.Tables.Delete("dynamicTable");
            package.Save();
    }
```

As you can see, a very basic operation that kinda fails.
If anyone knows of a solution to remove a table from a spreadsheet with EPPlus, please share. Would be much appreciated.

Comment: Obviously *not* a basic thing - a table is a name for a range, *not* the range or its contents. Removing it can break any functions that use it, connections that fill it etc. If it was basic, modifying the XML itself would work. Have you tried this with a simple sheet, ie only one table, no formatting, connections etc? Is the table used in any formulas, filled by connections?

Comment: That's a bug. Deleting a table modifies the worksheet part but *doesn't* remove the table part either for the tables "folder" or the "Content_Types" file inside the package. Unfortunately, EPPlus doesn't expose the actual OpenXML package or its parts so there is no way to remove the orphans manually.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. By basic I was referring to the operation exposed by epplus (a simple '.Delete()'). I've tried to alter the xml as mentioned in the question. Nothing happens. It just ignores it.

Comment: Delete isn't that simple, in fact it was only added in the latest version. An xlsx file actually contains many parts (sheets, styles, tables, etc). It's not enough to remove a Table reference from a sheet, the part itself has to be removed and the package indexes and content_types.xml updated. Going through the code I found that EPPluss doesn't do that - it only deletes the table reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have trouble with the `Delete` method as well.  I can't even compile when I reference it half the time.  Strange.

What if you delete the reference to the table via xml.  If it is the only table in the ws or you know the exact order it is pretty easy to do:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Table_Delete_Test()
{
    //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36359047/unable-to-delete-table-using-epplus
    //Throw in some data
    var datatable = new DataTable("tblData");
    datatable.Columns.AddRange(new[]
    {
        new DataColumn("Col1", typeof (int)), new DataColumn("Col2", typeof (int)), new DataColumn("Col3", typeof (object))
    });

    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        var row = datatable.NewRow();
        row[0] = i; row[1] = i * 10; row[2] = Path.GetRandomFileName();
        datatable.Rows.Add(row);
    }

    var fi = new FileInfo(@"c:\temp\Table_Delete_Test.xlsx");
    if (fi.Exists)
        fi.Delete();

    //Create a worksheet with tables to later open and look for tables (note that EPPlus does not create the table objects until save)
    using (var pck = new ExcelPackage(fi))
    {
        var workbook = pck.Workbook;

        var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add("source");
        worksheet.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(datatable, true);
        worksheet.Cells["A12"].LoadFromDataTable(datatable, true);

        var table1 = worksheet.Tables.Add(worksheet.Cells["A1:C11"], "TableTest1");
        var table2 = worksheet.Tables.Add(worksheet.Cells["A12:C22"], "TableTest2");

        pck.Save();
    }

    //Open the test workbook and delete the second table
    using (var pck = new ExcelPackage(fi))
    {
        var workbook = pck.Workbook;
        var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.First();

        var wsXml = worksheet.WorksheetXml;
        var nsm = new XmlNamespaceManager(wsXml.NameTable);
        var nsuri = wsXml.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI;
        nsm.AddNamespace("m", nsuri);

        //Remove reference to the second table which should be last
        var tablePartsNode = wsXml.SelectSingleNode("m:worksheet/m:tableParts", nsm);
        tablePartsNode.RemoveChild(tablePartsNode.LastChild);

        pck.Save();
    }
}
```

So it goes from this:

[image]

to this:

[image]

But if you need to do it by `Table.Name` that is not so easy.  You would have to get the `RelationshipID` which Epplus has marked as internal.  The RID is based on the zip package so to get that you either fork and modify Epplus to expose it or you open the XLSX as a `ZipArchive` and get the RID from that - kind of a pain.

Comment: Hi, your solution does the trick, with only one thing to mention. The table indeed does go away, but if I try to put a new table in it's place, I get an error stating that the table ranges collide. In addition to this, a call to the delete function is needed. Pretty strange, the function seems to half work.

Comment: This only does half the job. An `xlsx` is actually a zip package that contains many parts, which are stored as separate XML files. Modifying the worksheet XML only removes the *reference* to the table part, it doesn't actually remove the `table1.xml` file or the index entries

Comment: Deletion would be easy using the OpenXML SDK which unfortunately, isn't available as a Nuget package. That's why EPPlus doesn't use it. Without it, the System.IO.Packaging namespace can manage the package *parts*, but updating related files will require modifying the relevant XML files directly

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos  Correct about the zip.  To remove the table.xml file you could open the package using ZipPackage and find the file to delete.  BUT, if you open and save the file with excel it will actually stripout the file for you which is probably safer.

Comment: @CosminIonascu  Good point about adding a new table.  I agree, strange.  Maybe worth posting an issue on the Epplus codeplex page.